# Optimizing code using semaphore to control Netty channel pool

Tags: java, optimization, concurrency, netty

I am using Netty to exchange messages between a client and server. For this, I am maintaining a channel pool on client side. Please help me in optimizing this code.

```
public class Client{
    private static final Logger s_logger = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);
    private static volatile Client s_client;
    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private boolean[] used = null;
    private Semaphore available = null;
    private Channel[] channels = null;
    private final Bootstrap b;
    public static final AtomicInteger USED_CHANNELS = new AtomicInteger();
    public static final AtomicInteger SEMAPHORE_COUNT = new AtomicInteger();
    private Client(String host, int port){
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        used = new boolean[Config.getMaxConnections()];
        available = new Semaphore(Config.getMaxConnections());
        channels = new Channel[Config.getMaxConnections()];
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        final ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> channelInitializer = new  BasicNioClientChannelInitializer();
        b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(workerGroup)
         .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(channelInitializer)
         .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    }

    public static Client getClient() throws Exception{
        if(s_client == null){
            synchronized(Client.class){
                if(s_client==null){
                    s_client = new Client(Config.getServerIp(),Config.getServerPort());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int sendMessage(final String message) throws Exception{
        final String messageToSend = message + "\r\n";
        final Calendar sendStart = Calendar.getInstance();
        int responseCode = 200;
        available.acquire();
        SEMAPHORE_COUNT.incrementAndGet();
        Channel ch;
        boolean activeChannel;
        int i;
        synchronized(this){
            ch = null;
            activeChannel = false;
            for (i=0; i < Config.getMaxConnections(); i++){
                if (!used[i]) {
                    used[i] = true;
                    USED_CHANNELS.incrementAndGet();
                    ch = channels[i];
                    break;                    
                }
            }
            if(i == Config.getMaxConnections()){
                //Should never happen
                throw new Exception("No unsused connections.");
            }
            try{
                activeChannel = ch!=null? ch.isActive():false;
                if(!activeChannel){
                    if(ch!=null){
                        ch.close();
                    }            
                    ChannelFuture cf = b.connect(host,port);
                    boolean connect = cf.await(Config.getMaxWaitInMillisToConnect());
                    if(!connect){
                        throw new Exception("Unable to try connection to Server in " +Config.getMaxWaitInMillisToConnect()+"ms" );
                    }
                    ch = cf.channel();
                    channels[i] = ch;
                    activeChannel = ch.isActive();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                responseCode = 404;
                s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, "***** Could not Connect to Server ****");
                s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try{
            if(activeChannel){
                System.out.println("Sending to Server using Channel: " + i + " data: " + message);
                ChannelFuture future = ch.writeAndFlush(messageToSend);
            }else{
                throw new Exception("Unable to connect to Server.");
            } 
        }catch(Exception e){
            responseCode = 404;
            s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, "***** Could not Connect to Server ****");
            s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized(this){
            for (int j = 0; j < Config.getMaxConnections(); j++) {
                if (ch == channels[j]) {
                    if (used[j]) {
                        used[j] = false;
                        USED_CHANNELS.decrementAndGet();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        available.release();
        SEMAPHORE_COUNT.decrementAndGet();
        return responseCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing three, no 4 different concurrency mechanisms in this code...

- you have a volatile static instance... that's also locked by a synchronization block in `getClient` ... in a double-check-locked class... hmmmm OK, that's why it is volatile, to create the singleton.
- you have a Semaphore
- you synchronize on 'this' twice in `sendMessage()`
- you have AtomicIntegers for channel counts

Note, that you synchronize on two different Objects at different times too... you sync on the `Client.class` as well as an instance of the Client (`this`).

Further, your concurrency is broken.... you are doing network activity in the sentMessage() class, and it calls:

```
available.acquire();
```

but, it does not use a try/finally block to manage that semaphore (and, since you are locked on the semaphore, why do you need the `USED_CHANNELS` at all?)

Oh, that's static.

But, it is a major bug to not use a finally block for the `available.release()` because you will leak semaphores as your code fails on intermittent problems.... which *will* happen.

Hmmm, your levels of locking are so complicated, that I would recommend a rewrite.

It is apparent that you have been reading up on the volatile-double-check-locking solutions, but why not just use the now-recommended [enum Singleton pattern](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html)?

Use a single strategy for locking in the sendMessage: the atomics, synchronized, and semaphore combination are too much. Use just one strategy.

As it stands, it is essentially too complicated for me to even verify if the concurrency is safe, let alone efficient.

Comment: @rofl I have removed the Atomic instances. you are right with try finally and enum singleton suggestions, i will do that too. I need to verify that do i need synchronized(this) blocks or the semaphore takes care of that? I used synchronized block on top of semaphore block because i am accessing the shared resource channels[] (read as well write).

Comment: Hi @rolfl I am accepting your answer and using your suggestions. Please have a look at the new code http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64220/optimizing-code-using-semaphore-to-control-netty-channel-pool-part-2