# Optimizing code using semaphore to control Netty channel pool - Part 2

Tags: java, optimization, concurrency, netty

Please have a look at my original question:
[Optimizing code using semaphore to control Netty channel pool](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63920/optimizing-code-using-semaphore-to-control-netty-channel-pool)

I have made some changes as pointed out by @rolfl 
The new code is as follows. Is this better? Can i remove the synchronization blocks with some other methodology?

```
public enum Client{
    INSTANCE(Config.getServerIp(),Config.getServerPort());
    private static final Logger s_logger = Logger.getLogger(Client.class);
    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private boolean[] used = null;
    private Semaphore available = null;
    private Channel[] channels = null;
    private final Bootstrap b;

    private Client(String host, int port){
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        used = new boolean[Config.getMaxConnections()];
        available = new Semaphore(Config.getMaxConnections());
        channels = new Channel[Config.getMaxConnections()];
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        final ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> channelInitializer = new  BasicNioClientChannelInitializer();
        b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(workerGroup)
         .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(channelInitializer)
         .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    }

    public int sendMessage(final String message) throws Exception{
        final String messageToSend = message + "\r\n";
        int responseCode = 200;
        available.acquire();
        try {
            Channel ch;
            boolean activeChannel;
            int i;
            synchronized (this) {
                ch = null;
                activeChannel = false;
                for (i = 0; i < Config.getMaxConnections(); i++) {
                    if (!used[i]) {
                        used[i] = true;
                        ch = channels[i];
                        break;                        
                    }
                }
                if (i == Config.getMaxConnections()) {
                    //Should never happen
                    throw new Exception("No unsused connections.");
                }
                try {
                    activeChannel = ch != null ? ch.isActive() : false;
                    if (!activeChannel) {
                        if (ch != null) {
                            ch.close();
                        }                        
                        ChannelFuture cf = b.connect(host, port);
                        boolean connect = cf.await(Config.getMaxWaitInMillisToConnect());
                        if (!connect) {
                            throw new Exception("Unable to try connection to Server in " + Config.getMaxWaitInMillisToConnect() + "ms");
                        }
                        ch = cf.channel();
                        channels[i] = ch;
                        activeChannel = ch.isActive();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    responseCode = 404;
                    s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, "***** Could not Connect to Server ****");
                    s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                if (activeChannel) {
                    System.out.println("Sending to Server using Channel: " + i + " data: " + message);
                    ChannelFuture future = ch.writeAndFlush(messageToSend);
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to connect to Server.");
                }                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                responseCode = 404;
                s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, "***** Could not Connect to Server ****");
                s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (this) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Config.getMaxConnections(); j++) {
                    if (ch == channels[j]) {
                        if (used[j]) {
                            used[j] = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            available.release();
        }        
        return responseCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much simpler code to read, and understand, than the previous version.

The `INSTANCE` singleton can probably be improved slightly by removing the Config calls from the `INSTANCE` declaration, and putting them in the constructor. Similarly, calling the `Config.getMaxConnections()` would be useful in the INSTANCE constructor too. The semaphore and channels should also be final....

A system like:

```
INSTANCE;

private final String host;
private final int port;
private final int maxConnections;
private final boolean[] used;
private final Semaphore available;
private final Channel[] channels;
private final Bootstrap b;    

private Client() {
    this.host = Config.getServerIp();
    this.port = Config.getServerPort();
    this.maxConnections = Config.getMaxConnections();
    used = new boolean[maxConnections];
    available = new Semaphore(maxConnections);
    channels = new Channel[maxConnections];
    .....
```

Using the above system makes all the private fields immutable, which helps with concurrency.

But, now that your code is also much easier to read, it is also apparent that there is a trick you can do that would simplify things a lot more.....

What you want is just one Queue and a synchronized mechanism for pulling from, and returning to it. Some code will be easier to explain with than text. Note one more important thing, your method was doing too much, which made it very complicated. By extracting the 'get a channel' and 'return a channel' methods, the sendMessage becomes much simpler...

You will need to extend this code to match your channel system, and logging, etc. The only thing that's real here is the single use of a synchronized. There is no other concurrency needed... (no semaphores, locks, or other tools):

```
private final int maxConnections;
private final Deque<Channel> queue = new LinkedList<>();
private int currentConnections = 0;

private Client() {
    maxConnections = Config.getMaxConnections();
    .... set up the BootStrap too.
}

// wait for, or create a channel
private Channel acquireChan() {
    synchronized(queue) {
        do {
            while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                if (currentConnections < maxConnections) {
                    // no idle channels, and we have space for another
                    // create a channel, and add it to the queue.
                    // hopefully it will be there when we go around the loop.
                    Channel newChan = b.createChannel();
                    currentConnections++;
                    queue.add(newChan);
                } else {
                    // otherwise wait a second, and loop again.
                    // if a channel is returned in the interim, we will be notified.
                    queue.wait(1000);
                }
            }
            // OK, there's an available channel, make sure it is usable.
            Channel toUse = queue.removeFirst();
            if (toUse.isActive()) {
                // great, good to go, use it.
                return toUse;
            }
            // the toUse connection is dead, throw it away.
            currentConnections--;
        } while (true);
    }
}

private void returnChan(Channel chan) {
    synchronized(queue) {
        queue.addLast(chan);
        queue.notifyAll();
    }

}

public int sendMessage(final String message) throws Exception{
    final String messageToSend = message + "\r\n";
    int responseCode = 200;
    Channel ch = acquireChan();
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending to Server using Channel: " + i + " data: " + message);
        ChannelFuture future = ch.writeAndFlush(messageToSend);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        responseCode = 404;
        s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, "***** Could not Connect to Server ****");
        s_logger.log(Level.FATAL, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 404;
    } finally {
        returnChan(ch);
    }
    return 200;
}
```